# Pushing artifacts to the Nexus using Jenkins maven-release-plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus, maven-release-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

In my Jenkins dashboard, I'm using **maven-release-plugin (v0.16.2)** to perform a maven release to Nexus repository. I have some issues while using this plugin.

[image]

**Issue 1:**

As shown in the image, it uses `<project_name>-<release_version>` as the SCM default tag. But I want to change it as `v<release_version>` value. Therefore, I have added the following change into my project pom.xml file's plugin section.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```

But still, it uses the aforementioned default tag. Is there any other configuration I have to do in Jenkins or pom.xml file?

**Issue 2:**

I have configured my pom.xml file with `distributionManagement` section to push my built artifact to the Nexus repository as follows.

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>releases</id>
      <name>Release Distribution Repository</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

With this configuration, Jenkins pushes all the project built artifacts (packaging JAR artifact + dependency XML artifacts in M2) to the given Nexus repository successfully. But in my case, I want to deploy only the JAR file to the Nexus repository (excluding other dependency XML files). Is it possible to do with this Jenkins maven release plugin? Deploy only a specific file or directory?

Comment: I don't realy understand your issue 2: If you deploy a jar, you need to deploy the `pom.xml` as well. Nexus needs a `pom.xml` for every jar.

Comment: Actually, in my case, I have some XML files as its dependencies (not the pom file). I just want to deploy my package without these XML files.

Comment: Maven does not deploy dependencies.

Comment: But I can find dependency XML files in the Nexus repository.

Comment: Or is there any configuration or property to point what file need to deploy?

Comment: Could you give me an example of such a file?

Comment: I have a custom plugin for that. Can you explain me how maven release:prepare and release:perform works?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? It changes version numbers and runs a new build (inside the other build)  in a clean directory? It furthermore checks in the built and the next version number in the git/svn.